# How can I put the rows on an specific column in a int[]? Visual Studio

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, ado.net

So, I have a table named Muestras(I created it with Access). It has only one column called "Muestras" also. It only has random numbers (33,83,42, etc), a total of 30.

I want to put all of these numbers inside an `int[]`. How can I do it?

```
OleDbConnection conexionMuestra = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\Muestra_pv.accdb");

OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Muestra", conexionMuestra);

DataTable tablaM = new DataTable();
adaptador.Fill(tablaM);
```

Comment: Do you have to use Access to store your samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a `DataTable` with one column and you need an `int[]`?

One way:

```
int[] result = tablaM.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<int>(0)) // or via column-name r.Field<int>("Muestras")
    .ToArray();
```

if it's actually a string column you need to parse it first:

```
int[] result = tablaM.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>(0)))  
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an arrayList if the table is going to continue to grow with a foreach loop or a while loop.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

while(tablaM.hasrows)
  {
al.add("data");
}
```

my syntax is probably off as I haven't used c# in a while but that should give you an idea